# Transaction across EJB and CDI beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, cdi

We've inherited an application that uses both EJB and CDI, with, e.g., EJBs calling methods of CDI beans.

I'm still unsure how transaction managament / handling works when calls are made from EJBs to CDI beans.

Let's assume the following simple example:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEjb {

    @Inject
    private MyCdi myCdi;
    
    public void doMyEjbStuff() {
        myCdi.doMyCdiStuff();
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyCdi {

    public void doMyCdiStuff() {
        // some database operations ...
        throw new RuntimeException("Error");
    }
}
```

Now `doMyEjbStuff()` is called outside a transaction context, so when it's called a new transaction is created.

In this case I would expect that the transaction created when `doMyEjbStuff()` is called spans the call to `doMyCdiStuff()` and gets rolled back due to the exception. The log should show an `javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted` message. Is this correct?

Would anything change if I would annotate `doMyCdiStuff()` with `@Transactional`?

What would happen if I annotate `doMyCdiStuff()` with `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)`? Now a `TransactionalException` is thrown, I guess. Would this exception cause the transaction started by calling `doMyEjbStuff()` to roll back?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer to the best of my experience, but you should probably experiment a bit too to verify. In general, I think you got most things right.

First, in a JEE/JakartaEE application server, the transaction mechanism supporting EJB transactions and CDI transactions is the same. In fact the CDI `@Transactional` annotation is specified in the JTA specification.

EJBs start or join a transaction by default, so when `MyEjb.doMyEjbStuff()` is called, it will always run inside a transaction. This transaction will span to the `MyCdi.doMyCdiStuff()` method.

> The log should show an javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted message.

I am not sure what the log will show, this might even be implementation-specific. But the transaction *will* be rolled back, as soon as the `RuntimeException` hits the EJB transaction interceptor. The `RuntimeException` is not an *application exception*, so it causes the transaction to rollback and the container to throw an `EJBException` that wraps it. (EJB 3.2 specs, ch. 9.2.2)

> Would anything change if I would annotate `doMyCdiStuff()` with `@Transactional`?

The JTA spec for the `@Transactional` annotation says that a `RuntimeException` will mark the transaction for rollback (JTA 1.2 spec, ch.3.7). So the current transaction. i.e. the one started by the EJB will be marked for rollback if the `RuntimeException` hits the Transactional interceptor. Since nothing is catching the exception, it will pass from the JTA/CDI Transactional interceptor, who will mark the transaction for rollback, then reach the EJB transaction interceptor (or equivalent) which will also mark the transaction for rollback. So in this case nothing changes.

There would be a subtle difference if the EJB actually caught the `RuntimeException` and did something after it: without the JTA/CDI `@Transactional` the exception never reaches the container, so the "something" will be called and the overall transaction may succeed. If `@Transactional` is there, the current transaction is marked for rollback anyway. Stuff after the `catch(RuntimeException e)` will run and seemingly complete successfully, but the overall work will be rolled back. Watch out for this case, if the "something" has side-effects!

> What would happen if I annotate `doMyCdiStuff()` with `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)`?

Following the discussion above, the current transaction, i.e. the one started by `@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)`, will be rolled back. But noone is catching the exception, so it propagates to the EJB and rolls back that transaction too. And gets thrown, wrapped in an `EJBException`. If the EJB caught the exception, only the internal transaction would be rolled back.